# How do i change the color of a text element?

Tags: xslt

Below code is not working, whats the correct way to change the text color?

```
<xsl:text color="green">Sold</xsl:text>
```

Comment: XSLT doesn't have any concept of colours itself. To change the color of text depends on what actual format you are outputting. This could be HTML, XSL-FO, or some other language, for example. Can you show a sample of what you are currently outputting? Thanks!

Comment: You have to style the element around the xsl:text, because XSLT doen't do styling.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:text color="green">Sold</xsl:text>
```

There is no attribute like color in xslt. You must provide format and input where you want to color your text.

Comment: so theres no possible way i can make anything a different color in xsl?

Comment: There probably is, but the method depends on which output format you use.